# The command "tsc" --sourcemap --target ES5 exited with code 9009

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple ts like this one below and when I hit F5 in Visual Studio 2013 Community I got the error in the title.

```
class Person {
    Name: string;
    ChangeLabel(lblResult: HTMLLabelElement, value:string) {
        lblResult.innerText = value;
    }
}

var SomePerson = new Person();
SomePerson.Name = "Joel RedenBury";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instruction given here from CodePlex and it worked

Taking a look at the error message, this looks like a very old project that was not migrated to a 1.0 compiler. You can see it in the filepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc. More recent versions would have the version of TypeScript in the filepath (eg, for me it would be: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc)

You may need to create a new project and copy your existing files into it so that you have the updated configuration bits you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and was able to resolve it by finding the location of tsc.exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8 on my machine) and adding it to my PATH environment variable.